# Storing ReactJS components, images and css code in database and retrieving it to construct UI dynamically

Tags: css, reactjs, single-page-application, pouchdb

I want to know if anyone has worked on something like storing jsx/react ui component, images and css code in database in json format and then load it from some indexdb or no sql db and create UI at runtime. Is there any performance hit in this kind of architecture. Idea is to get the data from database and convert the json into html and render on desktop or mobile via cordova something.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

React JSX code is just JavaScript.  I would probably pre-compile JSX to JavaScript before storing it in a database however.  As far as CSS that's just text as well so yes that can also be stored and retrieved.   In regards to images, you typically will store those on a file system and just log the path to where that image can be found in your database.